# Why not all stop words are removed from a list

Tags: python

I want to remove stop words in a given list from the list of words that I created splitting a text by space to count top most frequent words. However not all stop words are removed I do not understand why.

I defined a function (split_into_words) to split text x into words using re.split(" ", x):

```
wordsList= split_into_words(x)  
wordsList = [item.replace("\n"," ") for item in wordsList] 

stopwords = open('stopword.txt') .read() 

new_list = []
for w in wordsList:
   if not w.lower () in stopwords:
    new_list.append(w)
print(new_list)
```

The list still includes many stop words and they appear among frequent 15 (among them of, by, the and other words).

Comment: `in stopwords` is checking substrings of one string, not individual words. Perhaps you want this to be a list (or a set)?

Comment: How to correct that!

Comment: Well, `.read()` returns a single string, not a list of words. Without seeing what your file looks like, you can either split the lines or commas, or whatever delimiter the words are separated by

Comment: stopwords = open('stopwordlist.txt') .read()
stopwords=[]
stopwords=[stopwords.replace("\n", " ") for i in stopwords] 
stopwords= [stopwords.split(" ") for i in stopwords]

I still have the stopwords they even appear more frequent.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] of the file contents

Comment: With `stopwords = open('stopwordlist.txt').read(); stopwords=[]`, you've just overwrote the string with an empty list. The following two lines then do nothing. Maybe start here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, here is what I’d do.

With `moby.txt` a text file containing [text from Moby Dick](https://gutenberg.org/files/2701/2701-0.txt) and `stopwords.txt` another file with the following content:

```
and or
in
```

We’ll remove those words from the text of `moby.txt`.

```py
# read moby.txt to a list of words
with open("moby.txt", "r") as f:
    moby = f.read().split()

# read the stop word list from stopwords.txt
with open("stopwords.txt", "r") as f:
    stopwords = f.read().split()

# now remove stop words from moby
clean_moby = []
for word in moby:
    if word.lower() not in stopwords:
        clean_moby.append(word)

# you can also do the above in a list comprehension
#clean_moby = [word for word in moby if word.lower() not in stopwords]

print(clean_moby)
```

Comment: Thank you all I think I managed!